# Get .NET CLR performance counters for a windows service?

Tags: .net, performancecounter

How can one get .[NET CLR* performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a windows service?

Using [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) there is no instance related to my service but [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is able to show me specific counters for my service.

I see the instance if I ran the service as a console application. Am I missing any configuration? If so how does Process Explorer work anyway?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, start with the [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx) class
You can create some performance counter specific for your service and then they show in the performance monitor.

Comment: I already use custom performance counters for application specific purposes. I want to see .NET CLR counters for my application. I'm able to see those using Process Explorer but I want to see them in Perfmon so to have the data logged periodically along my custom counters.